# does this limit diverge?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've used little o notation; as x approaches positive infinity n goes to infinity way faster than other stuff. Therefore, I've omitted the other parts, and this is the final limit:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} {n+o(n)\over \sqrt(n+o(n)) - \sqrt(n+o(n))} * cos(1)$$
(the other functions were, log, a limited function, cosine, and a square root).

this part $\sqrt(n+o(n)) - \sqrt(n+o(n))$ cancels out, **therefore the limit goes to infinity**, because $(stuff) / 0 = infinity $.

Am I wrong?

Comment: The $\sqrt n$ do cancel out but it still remains in the denominator a $o(\sqrt n)$  which could as well go to $\infty$.

Comment: You cannot cancel the $o(n)$ ! For example, the first one could be twice the second one ...

Comment: Just as a technical matter, why are you taking the limit in $x$ when your expression is written in terms of $n.$

Comment: @ChrisLeary ah I didn't noticed that, it's a typo, I should've written n->+infinity

Comment: so the limit goes to infinity as well, right? because in the denominator I have "n" which goes to infinity, and in the denominator I have a o(sqrt(n)) which goes to infinity way slower than the numerator, so I don't consider the denominator, right?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini: yes, the limit will still go to $\infty$ for this reason, but you cannot say that “$\sqrt{n+o(n)} - \sqrt{n+o(n)}$ cancels out”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarification, little o notation usually means $f(n) = o(n)$ means $f$ grows slower than $n$, namely,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = 0 
$$

To avoid confusion, let us consider $f_1(n), f_2(n)$ and $f_3(n)$ that are all $o(n)$. The original expression is reformulated by
$$
\frac{n+f_1(n)}{\sqrt{n+f_2(n)}-\sqrt{n+f_3(n)}} = \frac{(n+f_1(n))(\sqrt{n+f_2(n)}+\sqrt{n+f_3(n)})}{(n+f_2(n))-(n+f_3(n))}
$$
Note that the numerator is order of $n^{3/2}$ while the denominator is $f_2(n)-f_3(n) = o(n)$. Henceforth, the absolute value of the expression will diverge. If the sign of $f_2(n)-f_3(n)$ is known to be positive (negative) for all large enough $n$, then one can concludes that the limit is positive (negative) infinity. If the sign of $f_2(n)-f_3(n)$ switches infinitely often, then the limit does not exist.